# Storing initialized drivers in a Java List but appearing null on fetching them

Tags: java, selenium

In my selenium code in Java I have to use multiple drivers. So I am declaring them in the class and storing them in a list. Then in a method I am initializing them but when I fetching them using get(index function) I am getting their value as null but if I use them directly then value is appearing. See Below:

Here I am declaring my drivers:

```
public static WebDriver driver1 = null;
public static WebDriver driver2 = null;
public static WebDriver driver3 = null;
public static WebDriver driver4 = null;
public static WebDriver driver5 = null;
public static WebDriver driver6 = null;
```

Now I am storing them in a list just after that:

```
public List<WebDriver> Drivers = Arrays.asList(driver1, driver2, driver3, driver4, driver5, driver6);
```

Then in a method I am initializing the drivers which is called from my tests.

```
public void initializeDrivers(String driver) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException {

    if(driver.equals("driver1") && driver1==null) {
        System.out.println("First browser is opening");
        driver1 = getDriver();
    } else if(driver.equals("driver2") && driver2==null) {
        System.out.println("Second browser is opening");
        driver2 = getDriver();
    } else if(driver.equals("driver3") && driver3==null) {
        System.out.println("Third browser is opening");
        driver3 = getDriver();
        System.out.println("Login with qa softphone 1");
        SFLP.softphoneLogin(driver3, CONFIG.getProperty("qa_test_site_name"), CONFIG.getProperty("qa_user_3_username"), CONFIG.getProperty("qa_user_3_password"));
        //setDefaultSetting(driver3);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver4") && driver4==null) {
        System.out.println("Fourth browser is opening");
        driver4 = getDriver();
    } else if(driver.equals("driver5") && driver5==null) {
        System.out.println("Fifth browser is opening");
        driver5 = getDriver();
    } else if(driver.equals("driver6") && driver6==null) {
        System.out.println("Sixth browser is opening");
        driver6 = getDriver();
    }
}
```

Code for getDriver:

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {

    WebDriver driver = null;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    }


    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); 
    options.addArguments("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream"); 
    options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");

    //Initializing a driver 
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    return driver;
}
```

Now when I fetch drivers directly as driver1 then I am getting the driver in it but when I fetch it using the list Drivers.get(1) I get value as null. Any help is well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the code for getDriver method?

Comment: @Murthi, added the code for getDriver.

Comment: list index starts with 0. may be you can try with Drivers.get(0) and it should be called after launching the browser.

Comment: I did that (Drivers.get(0) ). I am launching the browser and after that I am getting the values from list but still its not working. But when I simply do with driver1 then its working. Is it because I am storing the value in the list just after declaring the drivers and after that I am launching the browser?

Comment: if you use array aslist it will create internal array, so it will not be same. please refer my answer. it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as given below.

Change 1: Drivers should be static.

```
public static List<WebDriver> Drivers = Arrays.asList(driver1, driver2, driver3, driver4, driver5, driver6);
```

Change 2:

```
public void initializeDrivers(String driver) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException {

    if(driver.equals("driver1") && driver1==null) {
        System.out.println("First browser is opening");
        driver1 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(0, driver1);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver2") && driver2==null) {
        System.out.println("Second browser is opening");
        driver2 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(1, driver2);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver3") && driver3==null) {
        System.out.println("Third browser is opening");
        driver3 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(2, driver3);
        System.out.println("Login with qa softphone 1");
        SFLP.softphoneLogin(driver3, CONFIG.getProperty("qa_test_site_name"), CONFIG.getProperty("qa_user_3_username"), CONFIG.getProperty("qa_user_3_password"));
        //setDefaultSetting(driver3);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver4") && driver4==null) {
        System.out.println("Fourth browser is opening");
        driver4 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(3, driver4);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver5") && driver5==null) {
        System.out.println("Fifth browser is opening");
        driver5 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(4, driver5);
    } else if(driver.equals("driver6") && driver6==null) {
        System.out.println("Sixth browser is opening");
        driver6 = getDriver();
        Drivers.set(5, driver6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you brief the change in `Change 2` just like the way you did in `Change 1`? Thanks

Comment: In change 2. I am just change the value of the Drivers list. because it is pointing to null value when it is initialized. To change the value of list with position, we can use set method of it.

Comment: Thanks Murthi, but will it work if I change my code driver1 = getDriver(); to Drivers.get(0) =  getDriver(); ??

Comment: No, change it as Drivers.set(0, getDriver());